# Two-factor authentication when your device is not present

Tags: icloud, apple-id, two-factor-authentication

What happens when you have two-factor authentication enabled for your account, your iPhone gets stolen or lost and you have to login on e.g. an Android device to activate Find my iPhone and you have no other Apple devices with you?

Is there a way to still get into iCloud to activate Find my iPhone?

Comment: Hi, welcome to Ask Different. Unless the web browser on that Android device is trusted, you will need a six-digit verification code. That's the way two-factor authentication, and it can definitely lock you out, unless you have more than one device/web browser that is trusted. See the FAQ section in this KB article: https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204915 for more information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a way to still get into iCloud to activate Find my iPhone?

Yes, you can login to iCloud to activate Find My iPhone. You can get a verification code via SMS or voice call on your trusted phone number.

Refer to this Apple Support document:

- https://support.apple.com/kb/HT204915

> ### What if I can't access a trusted device or didn't receive a verification code?
>
> If you're signing in and don’t have a trusted device handy that can display verification codes, you can have a code sent to your trusted phone number via text message or an automated phone call instead. Click Didn't Get a Code on the sign in screen and choose to send a code to your trusted phone number.

Comment: Unless you can change the trusted phone number it may have been with the stolen phone...

Comment: @SolarMike Seconded. But in such unfortunate instance, it's generally recommended to report the theft and regain access to the phone number.

Comment: Then that should be the answer